# Can the handle be same on two windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, handle

Suppose if a window with handle 123456 is closed and another window is opened. Can Windows assign handle 123456 to the new window in the rarest possibility?

Comment: It's *possible*, but highly unlikely. So to all intents and purposes you can assume to that the two windows will have different handles.

Comment: I had a real bug once many years ago where the window handle had gotten properly closed but not the "paint thread".  The thread had it's own copy of the HWND handle.  It would continually call GetDC(hwnd) and GetClientRect(hwnd) and repaint the entire window space. Then one day my boss wanted to know why my UI control was overlaying itself on top of his Outlook email window while both apps were running. Windows had reassigned the HWND value for an Outlook window, but my paint thread was still active!  I quickly fixed my bug to ensure the thread exited before the HWND was closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no guarantee anywhere that Windows won't immediately re-use a handle. In practice, all extant implementations take steps to try to avoid re-using handles.

Comment: The avoidance algorithm is not infallible though.

Comment: I am only using handles to compare two windows.

Comment: @Programmer: What do you mean by "comparing two windows"? Are you comparing their dimensions, the window title, etc.? Or are you really interested in comparing the handle vluaes? (If so, what makes you think comparing handle values give you any useful information?)

Comment: I am using `EnumWindows` to add the windows in a `List<IntPtr>`. My app calls it every time a `WINDOW_CREATED` or `WINDOW_DESTROYED` message is generated. To compare what windows were closed I use their handles.